# Access Changeable values from Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have a problem about reading an excel file. If I save file as this picture

[image]

I receive an error because this column's values are

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: it's related with file saving file

Answer (score 0):

Cells have **value** and **formatting.** The values of your cells are 10-digit numbers. They are displayed like in the first picture because column width is not enough to fit them.